# Efficiency help on inserting and deleting rows from a large DB table ~100M rows

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I am inserting rows from a large DB table into an archive table and then deleting the inserted rows. My code is as follows:

```
-- insert here
insert into DEST_DB.dbo.ARCHIVE_TABLE
select SRC_DB.dbo.ORIG_TABLE.*
from SRC_DB.dbo.ORIG_TABLE
where SRC_DB.dbo.ORIG_TABLE.ORDER_ID
IN ( select #tmp_table.order_id from #tmp_table )

-- delete here
delete from SRC_DB.dbo.ORIG_TABLE
where SRC_DB.dbo.ORIG_TABLE.ORDER_ID
IN ( select #tmp_table.order_id from #tmp_table )
```

The size of the `#tmp_table.order_id` table is currently set to 10K rows and the temp table will be filled and cleared in a loop, which means it will be used for my insertion and deletion operations within each loop iteration.

I have `UNIQUE UNCLUSTERED` indexes on the ORDER_ID column for my SRC_DB.dbo.ORIG_TABLE

My problem is when I try my stored procedure, it just seems to halt on processing this table.

I understand I may not have the most efficient solutions and would like to hear criticism and suggestions on how I can improve my stored procedure.

Thanks

Comment: Needs more investigation. Is the eproblem populating the temp table (in same sp ?) using an in instead of a join in your insert and deletes. No index on your temp table? The index on orig table not being used. Can't say from here. Get some times of the various stages, and use Explain to see what it's doing. Put just a few records in your table to cut down the thumb twiddling time

Comment: What do you mean "it seems to halt"? Do you get an error, or does it appear to take a long time?

Comment: Also, is the archiving you are doing an attempt to move data offline, or to address a performance problem when reading or writing new data?  Some RDBMS cannot get an efficient plan with a large include statement. Try JOINing the temp table on order_id.

Comment: What I mean by "it seems to halt" is I put in print statements and it just never gets to where it would like to get to. No errors, warnings, nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try a PK on #tmp_table and dropping the count down

```
insert into DEST_DB.dbo.ARCHIVE_TABLE
select SRC_DB.dbo.ORIG_TABLE.*
from SRC_DB.dbo.ORIG_TABLE
join #tmp_table on #tmp_table.order_id = SRC_DB.dbo.ORIG_TABLE.order_id 
order by clustered index on DEST_DB.dbo.ARCHIVE_TABLE

delete SRC_DB.dbo.ORIG_TABLE 
join #tmp_table on #tmp_table.order_id = SRC_DB.dbo.ORIG_TABLE.order_id
```

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by PK?

Comment: Primary Key.  A join to a PK is faster.  One the lookup is faster and two it knows to stop looking when it finds a match as by denfinitino there cannot be two PK with the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedure is executing the code you provided?

Does this "it just seems to halt on processing this table" you never saw this SP finish - it's that slow?

Try smaller #tmp_table.order_id - 100 or 1000 rows.

Try changing WHERE clause like this:

```
-- insert here
insert into DEST_DB.dbo.ARCHIVE_TABLE
select SRC_DB.dbo.ORIG_TABLE.*
from SRC_DB.dbo.ORIG_TABLE
where exists
( select #tmp_table.order_id from #tmp_table where #tmp_table.order_id=SRC_DB.dbo.ORIG_TABLE.ORDER_ID)

-- delete here
delete from SRC_DB.dbo.ORIG_TABLE
where exists 
( select #tmp_table.order_id from #tmp_table where SRC_DB.dbo.ORIG_TABLE.ORDER_ID=#tmp_table.order_id)
```

Comment: Thanks i will give that a try and yes it just never finishes.